# how can i replace function atomically using shell scripts

Tags: bash, shell

First：in my shell scripts：

```
[root@localhost ~]# cat  calc.sh 
#! /bin/sh
calc_func()
{

    i=1;
    j=2;
    if [ $i -gt 0 ];then
        return $(($i+$j));
    fi
}   
calc_func  
echo $?
```

and then， in my text:

```
[root@localhost ~]# cat calc.txt 
sub_func()
{  

    i=100;
    j=200;
    if [ $i -gt 0 ];then
        return $(($i-$j));
    fi

}
```

and now, i want to replace the funciton body named calc_func in calc.sh with  sub_func's body in calc.txt; let it becomes to this:

```
[root@localhost ~]# cat  calc.sh 
#! /bin/sh
calc_func()
{

    i=100;
    j=200;
    if [ $i -gt 0 ];then
        return $(($i-$j));
    fi

}   
calc_func  
echo $?
```

i want to achieve it with shell scripts, how can i fix it ? tips:source or export couldn't be use .

Comment: Why can't you use `source`?

Comment: just use awk to `split` the two function by `{ }` and then as long as you have them stored in the array, just add the functions code you want in the other one...

Comment: I don't get it ... the function itself should be in one place (and that can be edited by hand) ... then all the calls to the function can be easily replaced with sed (if you have many scripts source the file that contains the function) or with a simple replace from vi, or your favorite editor, if it's just one file.

Comment: yeah， i tried some times， when the functions to be replaced is only one just like calc_func, that is okay...it is easy to achieve  it ,  but actually,the functions to be replaced is not only one,  i have to replace ten functions more at the same time.  so it relate to search some function name and function body

Answer (score 1):

You can do it fairly easily with `head`, `tail`, `sed` and `mv`. For example:

```
head -n 2 calc.sh >tmp.sh
sed -n '/{/,/}/p' calc.txt >> tmp.sh
tail -n2 calc.sh >> tmp.sh
mv calc.sh calc.sh.sav; mv tmp.sh calc.sh
```

You can do that as a one-liner, or as a short script.

Your original `calc.sh` is now in `calc.sh.sav` and your new `calc.sh` with the inner block from `calc.txt` is in `calc.sh`, e.g.

```
$ cat calc.sh
#! /bin/sh
calc_func()
{

    i=100;
    j=200;
    if [ $i -gt 0 ];then
        return $(($i-$j));
    fi

}
calc_func
echo $?
```